# Android Facebook sdk override login button

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have to create login in android application thorough facebook 
I make it through [Facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2) which is working perfectly with custom UI. ( i have customised Fb LoginButton in Xml)

Now i want to put login button in first activity and logout button in another activity which will be open after successfully logged in and custom dialog for logIn and logOut Process(i.e. Fb Login in Zomato)

I go through the fb docs but there is no relevant material for that
Need some suggestion or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put 1 Facebook Login button in Activity1 and 1 in Activity2.
They both will use same access token and other things to detect current login state.
Then, You can hide the Button from Activity1 if successfully logged in and do opposite in Activity2.